# Characteristic function of infinitely divisible measure has no zero.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I want to show that the characteristic function of an infinitely divisible measure $P$ has no zero, directly by using the fact that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a measure $P_n$, such that:

$$\varphi_P(t)=\Big(\varphi_{P_n}(t)\Big)^n$$

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You mean has no zeros?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for writing root.

Comment: It's because in a neighbourhood of that point you'd be taking an $n$th root, so $\varphi$ wouldn't be analytic. usual argument about branches of log function etc.

Comment: This is a standard result which you can find for instance in Sato's book or in [these lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00251) on p.14.